# New to PL SQL and need help for an update cursor and 2 tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here's my code! I want to update Port fees for the order starting the 11-01-01 but I also need a condition from another table. I need to know if my customers are from Canada or not. If they are from Canada the fees goes down of 0.5 and if it's outside Canada fees goes up of .10 but it does not work because of country type because it's coming from another table and I can't seems to declare the country. So I would like help to know how I can update the fees with our without a cursor. Thank you! :)

```
DECLARE

P_PAYS CLIENTS.PAYS%TYPE;
P_PORT COMMANDES.PORT%TYPE;
AUGMENTATION NUMBER;
CURSOR CURSEUR IS
SELECT A.CODE_CLIENT,NO_COMMANDE,NO_EMPLOYE,DATE_COMMANDE,PORT,PAYS
   FROM CLIENTS A 
   join COMMANDES B
   ON B.CODE_CLIENT = A.CODE_CLIENT
   WHERE DATE_COMMANDE > '11-01-01'
   FOR UPDATE;  


BEGIN

  FOR CLIENTS IN CURSEUR LOOP
    IF CLIENTS.P_PAYS = 'Canada' THEN
     AUGMENTATION := -.05; 
    ELSE 
    AUGMENTATION := .10;
    END IF;
    UPDATE CLIENTS
    SET  PORT = PORT + (PORT * AUGMENTATION)
    WHERE CURRENT OF CURSEUR;    
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table definitions and example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra identifier(`augmentation`) is not needed. Exchange `FOR CLIENTS IN CURSEUR` with `FOR c IN curseur` as `clients` being your table not the cursor, and then use the following statement along with removing the current `if` conditional statement

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR curseur IS
    SELECT cl.code_client,
           no_commande,
           no_employe,
           date_commande,
           port,
           pays
      FROM clients cl
      JOIN commandes co
        ON co.code_client = cl.code_client
     WHERE date_commande > date'2011-01-01'
       FOR UPDATE;

BEGIN
  FOR c IN curseur LOOP
    UPDATE clients
       SET port = ROUND(port * CASE WHEN c.pays = 'Canada' THEN .95 ELSE 1.1 END,2)
     WHERE code_client = c.code_client;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much it work out with some little tweeks! :)

Comment: One thing is weird is that my calculation are bad! like one of the fees for a Canadian customer is 65.4 in my table and 65.4 multiply by 0.05 is 3.27 so it should be 65.4 minus 3.27 to get 62.13 and I am getting ridiculous numbers and sometimes 0.